# Why I get only old release from maven?

Tags: eclipse, maven

I installed a fresh eclipse with maven, and when I try to add a dependency I get only old releases:

[image]

I try to update the project, but it did not work.

I try to remove the .m2 folder in my user profile, but it did not work.

Comment: "Index downloads are disabled, search results may be incomplete." Have you tried entering a newer version and just see if it gets downloaded?

Comment: Yes it downloads them, but I need to add group, artifcat and version manually

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that the search happens locally, and it will by default only search through dependencies you already downloaded. If you want to have a full search, you need to enable the setting Window > Preferences > Maven and enable "Download repository index updates on startup".

As far as I know, enabling this setting can have a pretty heavy impact on startup performance of Eclipse, so you might want to reconsider and just look for specific versions yourself (eg on http://search.maven.org/).

Alternatively, you can update the index once by opening the Maven repositories view under Window > Show View > Other, search for maven and open "Maven Repositories". Under Global Repositories, select "central", right click and select "Update Index". You may need to switch index details as well from minimal to full.